# Problema com DataReader junto de Thread

Tags: c#, thread, datagridview, backgroundworker

Estou com um problema ao adicionar os dados retornados de um `Select` no `Datagridview`. O problema na verdade ocorre quando eu faço o uso de `backGroundWorker` junto de um `ProgressBar`.

A código em específico que realiza o `Select` e logo em seguida adiciona no `Datagridview` os dados é:

```
FbCommand command_ObtemCliente_loja99 = new FbCommand("Select ctas.cdcliente, ctas.ljcliente, cli.nome from ctasreceber ctas, clientes cli where ctas.cdcliente = cli.cdcliente and ctas.ljcliente = cli.ljcliente and flgpagamento = 'A' and (flgexcluido <> 'S' or flgexcluido is null) group by ctas.cdcliente, cli.nome, ctas.ljcliente", ConexaoAoBanco_loja99);

ConexaoAoBanco_loja99.Open();

reader = command_ObtemCliente_loja99.ExecuteReader();


if (reader.HasRows)
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>{
            dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
        }));
    }
}

reader.Close();
ConexaoAoBanco_loja99.Close();
```

E o botão que chama executa tal função no meu código é:

```
gpbx_PesquisaDados.Visible = false;
gpbx_PesquisaPersonalizado.Visible = false;

bgWorkerIndeterminada.RunWorkerAsync();

//define a progressBar para Marquee
prgsbar_AgrupTotalDados.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
prgsbar_AgrupTotalDados.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 5;

//informa que a tarefa esta sendo executada.
lbl_Status.Text = "PROCESSANDO...";
```

Porém o que é me retornado, é um `Exception` na hora de adicionar os dados da consulta no `Datagridview` (dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber)

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There are no data to read.'

Eu testei o código sem o uso do `backGroundWorker`, no caso onde o botão que utilizo para chamar esta função, automaticamente já faz a consulta e inserção dos dados no `datagridview`. Desta forma, os dados são adicionados corretamente mas em seguida ocorre outro erro e a aplicação fecha.

Uma observação que notei: Caso a parte do código abaixo não exista:

```
dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>{
    dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
}));
```

Ou seja, esteja assim:

```
 dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.BeginInvoke(
      dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
```

"Funciona" em partes, pois os dados são adicionados no `Datagridview`, mas outro erro ocorre:

> controle '' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.

E aí a aplicação é encerrada.

O que posso fazer? Pois de um jeito "funciona" a inserção dos dados no `Datagridview`, mas outro erro logo ocorre. E da outra forma, os dados não chegam nem até o `Datagridview`, pois a aplicação já é encerrada imediatamente pelo `Exception`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize uma coleção tipada para representar esses dados.

Exemplo:

```
public class ClienteCtaReceberModel
{
    public string CdCliente {get;set;}
    public string NomeCliente {get;set;}
    public string Loja {get;set;}
}
```

dentro do processo do `backgroundworker`, você monta a lista:

```
string sql = "Select ctas.cdcliente, ctas.ljcliente, cli.nome from ctasreceber ctas, clientes cli where ctas.cdcliente = cli.cdcliente and ctas.ljcliente = cli.ljcliente and flgpagamento = 'A' and (flgexcluido <> 'S' or flgexcluido is null) group by ctas.cdcliente, cli.nome, ctas.ljcliente";


List<ClienteCtaReceberModel> lista = new List<ClienteCtaReceberModel>();

using (FbCommand command_ObtemCliente_loja99 = new FbCommand(sql, ConexaoAoBanco_loja99))
{
    ConexaoAoBanco_loja99.Open();
    using (IDataReader reader = command_ObtemCliente_loja99.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             lista.Add(new ClienteCtaReceberModel(){ CdCliente = reader[0].ToString(), Loja = reader[1].ToString(), NomeCliente = reader[2].ToString() });
        }
    }
}


e.Result = lista; //aqui você informa para o BackgroundWorker, que o resultado dele é uma lista de ClienteCtaReceberModel
```

Por fim, no evento `Completed` do `BackgroundWorker`, você recupera o `Result`, que é sua lista, e atribui como `DataSource` do `DataGridView`:

```
private void bgWorkerIndeterminada_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    List<ClienteCtaReceberModel> lista = e.Result as List<ClienteCtaReceberModel>;
    dtGridView_Resultados_Busca_CtasReceber.DataSource = lista;

}
```